# Differential of product function of prime powers?

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations, prime-numbers

Taking my prior [question](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/408396/differential-of-a-prime-power-function?noredirect=1#comment874066_408396), here comes follow up:

Let $p\in \Bbb P$ a prime and a prime power function:

$$\xi_p(x) = p^x$$

with $\xi_p\in \Bbb R^+$ and $x \in \Bbb R^+_0$

hence:

$$\xi'_p = \frac{d}{dx}\xi_p=\xi_p \log p$$

Is it mathematically correct that I conclude, if:

$$f(x)=\prod_p^\infty p^x$$

then follows:

$$\frac{f'}{f}=\sum_p^\infty\frac{\xi'_p}{\xi_p}=\sum_p^\infty \log p \qquad f\in \Bbb R^+$$

or are further conditions required?

Answer (score 3):

To start with, you have
$$
  f(x) = \begin{cases}
\infty, &\text{ if }x>0
\\
1, &\text{ if }x = 0,
\\
0, &\text{ if } x <0
\end{cases}
$$
so it's hard to talk about its derivative.

Comment: $f$ defined only for positiv real and non zero, we may exclude also $f=1$. I will update the latter.

Comment: @al-Hwarizmi: for every positive real $x$, you have that $p^x \geq 1.5$ starting from some big prime numbers. For any fixed positive $x$ the partial products monotonically increase up to infinity.

Comment: thanks but I do not understand what you mean in respect to my questio, can you formulate your answer in a detailed Answer form?

Comment: It means your $f(x)$ is infinite, so differentiation does not apply.

Comment: Contradiction: That would say we should rather not exclude $x=0$ with $f=1$, and for a certain level of $p$, $f$ can turn to $1$ for ever.

Answer (score 0):

Ilya's comment is crucial; abovementioned definitly demands for a conditional distinction.

Let me try to take a step forward to a possible answer. I think one additional condition we would need, would be a kind of limitation of $f(x)$ such that:
$$ f(x) = \left\{
  \begin{array}{l l}
    \prod_{j=1}^\kappa p_j^x \; \leq n & \quad \text{if $j\leq\kappa$}\\
    1 & \quad \text{if $j>\kappa$}
  \end{array} \right.$$

and the canonical form of the fundamental theorem of arithmetic helps with a boundary condition:
$$n=\prod_{j=1}^\infty p^{m_j}_j \qquad ;m_j\in \Bbb N_0$$
while considering
$m_j=0$ for all $j>\kappa$.

that would give a limitation that $f$ does not grow infinitly for $p$, and $x=0$. I am sure there might be alternative formlations/notations perhaps much more comprehensiv.

Comment: The Fundamental Theorem of Arithmetic does *not* say $n=\prod_p^{\infty}p^m$. You may say, $n=\prod_p^{\infty}p^{m(n,p)}$ where, for each $n$, $m(n,p)=0$ for all but finitely many $p$. How you relate that to your proposed definition of $f(x)$ is not clear.

Comment: @GerryMyerson thanks. I tried to write it further out. See above. I still keep a final ANSWER open to the community.

Comment: Your "definition" of $f(x)$ makes no sense. "$f(x)=1$ if $j\gt k$" makes no sense at all; when all you are given is $x$, you don't have any $j$ or $k$, much less any way to tell which one is bigger. The first part is even worse, as you also don't have any $n$ when all you are given is $x$. Try to use your "definition" to calculate, say, $f(17)$, and you should quickly see how hopeless it is.

Comment: @GerryMyerson - you are right, above is hopeless. What would be your proposal? Perhaps $x$ needs to be defined as a function of $p$? What I seek for is a constraint that make $f(x)$ in a certain range (of FTA) differentiable.